# Azure AD login with with office 365 login

Tags: azure, microsoft-office-365, entra-id

We are using Office 365 for email and same AD is linked with azure to manage azure portal. This is working fine.

lets say company domain is mydomain.com

We have few VM in a Virtual Network and this VN is associated with a Azure AD
ad.mydomain.com

all users who need to access VMs, created on mydomain.com like

user1@mydomain.com
user2@mydomain.com
...

Now my question is - Can I simplify user login so that user can login to VM using their office 365 account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure AD on its own is [not the same as active directory](https://samcogan.com/azure-active-directory-is-not-active-directory/), you can't just join machines to it and use it the same way as on-premises AD.

You can, however, use a service called [Azure AD Domain Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/active-directory-ds/), to create domain controllers as a service based on your AAD domain. If you do this, and join your VMs to this AAD DS domain, then you can log in with your Azure AD/Office 365 accounts. Just be aware of the [limitations of AAD DS](https://samcogan.com/azure-ad-directory-service-new-features/).